# How do I test if my SSD uses compression?

Tags: linux, ssd, compression

I am thinking of running the filesystem with btrfs on my SSD. This might make the disk last longer or run faster, because if we compress the filesystem there is less to write. (I understand this is not the case with NTFS, as IIRC NTFS has to write the file uncompressed and compress it later). However, if the SSD itself uses compression, using a compressed filesystem is unlikely to help in this way.

I tried smartctl, which tells it is a LZT-128 with firmware version ZYA3, but I haven't been able to find information on whether this drive uses compression.

How can I test if my SSD uses compression?

Answer (score 1):

We can try writing psuedo-random vs. easily compressible data. For example, with the script

```
( sync
  dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=100M of=testfile.tmp
  time sync
  rm testfile.tmp
  dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100M of=testfile.tmp
  time sync
) 2>&1 | grep real
```

This script first writes 100MB of random data then writes 100MB of zeros, then times how long it takes this data to be synced to disk.

On the LZT-128 the script first gave

```
real    0m0.351s
real    0m0.306s
```

and on the next run gave

```
real    0m0.304s
real    0m0.316s
```

As this didn't demonstrate any performance difference between random writes and zeroed writes, this suggests that the drive doesn't use compression. In any case it demonstrates that they drive would be able to write small amounts of compressed data as quickly as uncompressed.